# Deploying Angular Universal to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops

I have an application which I have managed to convert to Angular Universal (at my clients request).
I ran my application by using the command `npm run serve:ssr` and pointed my browser to http://localhost:4000 which works.

Now I want to deploy. I have run `npm run build:ssr` which has created a dist folder.
The dist folder doesn't have the "normal" angular files in it. It is relatively sparse, it has:

- a **server.js**
- a **browser** folder
- and a **server** folder

If I ftp these to my azure site (as I used to do with the normal angular application), it doesn't work. I get a error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

So I tried to set up CI using VSTS and I followed some steps I found for publishing angular universal (although they were not very clear).
This is my **yaml** file:

```
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: npm

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 8.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 8.x

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build:ssr'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: server.js
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: prerender.js
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<my subscription>'
    WebAppName: firstApplication
    DeployToSlotFlag: true
    ResourceGroupName: Temp
    SlotName: develop
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
    ConfigurationSettings: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
```

I don't think it is right. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I followed answer by *r3plica*, and I had to do a slight modification and move the **dist/server** to the root dir and all went well.

If things do not work, always use **node** to point at **server.js**

```
node <path to server.js>
```

This tells you the most basic things you have gotten wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is mine and it works

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure CBW Dev'
    WebAppName: 'WebDev'
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
    GenerateWebConfig: false
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
```

Comment: That looks wrong to me mate, your `ng build --prod` is only building the client application (not angular universal). If you do a view source on your application, I am willing to bet you see an empty body (with your scripts, but no html).