# Angular 9 universal 9 deployment on IIS server with web.config? How to deploy angular 9 Server side rendering on IIS server

Tags: angular, iis, angular9, angular-universal

How to deploy Angular 9 Server side rendering on IIS server

What will be `web.config` for IIS

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the steps to create a sample app and deploy in iis:

1)Install the Angular 10 CLI and initialize a new project. (you can skip this step if you already created the app and installed npm)

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new angular-seo-app
```

2)Go back to your command-line interface, and start by navigating to your project's folder:

```
cd angular-seo-app

ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular-seo-app
```

The schematic will automatically add the required configurations and packages to your project and will even add an Express server.

The Express server will render a part of your Angular app and return HTML to the browser. The server runs on the 4000 port by default

3)Go back to your terminal and run the following commands:

```
npm run build:ssr 
npm run serve:ssr
```

This will build your project with SSR support and start the Express server from the http://localhost:4000 address.

You will see dist folder in your project folder.

[image]

4)Go to your windows server(C:\inetpub\wwwroot) and create an empty folder (name it ng-ssr for example)

[image]

5)Copy to dist folder into ng-ssr

6)Open C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ng-ssr\dist\angular-seo-app\server folder, you will find main.js file

[image]

7)copy main.js and paste it directly in ng-ssr folder

8)create web.conifg file in your ng-ssr folder and add below code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                 <match url="/*" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="StaticContent" stopProcessing="true">  
                  <match url="([\S]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ts|cscc|less|ico|html|map|svg))" />
                  <action type="None" />
            </rule>  
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
          <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
          <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
          <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
          <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
          <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/otf" />
         </staticContent>      
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

An IIS web.config file is an XML file containing rules for a particular site (or directory) on your web server. It is similar to a .htaccess file in Apache.
This file may contain rules setting 404, 403, etc. error pages for your site as well as redirection rules for older URLs.

Our web.config file is containing the URL rewrite rule,iis node setting, and mime type.

**Note: Download the [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [iisnodex64](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases/download/v0.2.21/iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x64.msi) , [iisnodex86](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases/download/v0.2.21/iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x86.msi)**

Now your website folder must look like this:

[image]

9)Create a Web Site in IIS

and add the folder path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ng-ssr

[image]

10)In the IIS, go to the Application Pool for the Web Site you created, change the .Net Framework Version to No Managed Code

[image]

Note: Make sure you assigned the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the ng-ssr folder.

[image]

browse your site:

[image]

Comment: I am stuck with this 500 error. he node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Gave permission and everything

Comment: @PriyankaArora I request you to create a new thread for your issue.

Comment: It would be immense help if you could please tell me how did you get iisnode folder. I installed from the link, have it in iis modules but how this folder is created in the site.

Comment: @PriyankaArora after installing the iisNode modules, the folder got generated automatically