# Angular universal not loading the routes when publishing to iis

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, angular-universal, iisnode

I added angular universal to a project and is running perfectly fine locally with no issues, but when I published it on iis and run the website I get a blank white screen with no errors. I downloaded URL Rewrite, Node js and iisnode, I checked a lot of feeds but none that actually helped.

I followed this tutorial [Link](https://www.thecodehubs.com/how-to-deploy-ssr-angular-universal-to-iis/). I also gave full access to IIS_Users

Any help would be appreciated.

Server.ts :

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {existsSync} from 'fs';
import {join} from 'path';

import {AppServerModule} from './src/main.server';
import 'localstorage-polyfill'


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/appname/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

function bootstrap() {
     platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
   };


 if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   bootstrap();
 } else {
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootstrap);
 }
```

If I go to http://localhost I get the blank white screen but when I go to http://localhost/index.html the page then loads

I checked the logs of the node server and it is printing out the following:

```
Node Express server listening on http://localhost:\\.\pipe\8e58c146-d5c8-4cc5-a8f5-0dada515a13a
```

When I view page source or inspect the page I get the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    
        <link href="assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
        <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@4.2.0/dist/css/coreui.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-7W1eMOzj3wRp1Oat/SJe+uPZ3lBB5YWlrjI9zeLbto2KkseMeJKSGAs4844qZPjz" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-black:#000;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-gray-100:#f8f9fa;--bs-gray-200:#e9ecef;--bs-gray-300:#dee2e6;--bs-gray-400:#ced4da;--bs-gray-500:#adb5bd;--bs-gray-600:#6c757d;--bs-gray-700:#495057;--bs-gray-800:#343a40;--bs-gray-900:#212529;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark:#212529;--bs-primary-rgb:13,110,253;--bs-secondary-rgb:108,117,125;--bs-success-rgb:25,135,84;--bs-info-rgb:13,202,240;--bs-warning-rgb:255,193,7;--bs-danger-rgb:220,53,69;--bs-light-rgb:248,249,250;--bs-dark-rgb:33,37,41;--bs-white-rgb:255,255,255;--bs-black-rgb:0,0,0;--bs-body-color-rgb:33,37,41;--bs-body-bg-rgb:255,255,255;--bs-font-sans-serif:system-ui,-apple-system,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue","Noto Sans","Liberation Sans",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";--bs-font-monospace:SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;--bs-gradient:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));--bs-body-font-family:var(--bs-font-sans-serif);--bs-body-font-size:1rem;--bs-body-font-weight:400;--bs-body-line-height:1.5;--bs-body-color:#212529;--bs-body-bg:#fff;--bs-border-width:1px;--bs-border-style:solid;--bs-border-color:#dee2e6;--bs-border-color-translucent:rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);--bs-border-radius:.375rem;--bs-border-radius-sm:.25rem;--bs-border-radius-lg:.5rem;--bs-border-radius-xl:1rem;--bs-border-radius-2xl:2rem;--bs-border-radius-pill:50rem;--bs-link-color:#0d6efd;--bs-link-hover-color:#0a58ca;--bs-code-color:#d63384;--bs-highlight-bg:#fff3cd}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:no-preference){:root{scroll-behavior:smooth}}body{margin:0;font-family:var(--bs-body-font-family);font-size:var(--bs-body-font-size);font-weight:var(--bs-body-font-weight);line-height:var(--bs-body-line-height);color:var(--bs-body-color);text-align:var(--bs-body-text-align);background-color:var(--bs-body-bg);-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}.fade{transition:opacity .15s linear}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce){.fade{transition:none}}.spinner-grow{display:inline-block;width:var(--bs-spinner-width);height:var(--bs-spinner-height);vertical-align:var(--bs-spinner-vertical-align);border-radius:50%;animation:var(--bs-spinner-animation-speed) linear infinite var(--bs-spinner-animation-name)}.spinner-grow{--bs-spinner-width:2rem;--bs-spinner-height:2rem;--bs-spinner-vertical-align:-.125em;--bs-spinner-animation-speed:.75s;--bs-spinner-animation-name:spinner-grow;background-color:currentcolor;opacity:0}.spinner-grow-sm{--bs-spinner-width:1rem;--bs-spinner-height:1rem}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce){.spinner-grow{--bs-spinner-animation-speed:1.5s}}.m-1{margin:.25rem!important}@charset "UTF-8";:root{--animate-duration:1s;--animate-delay:1s;--animate-repeat:1}</style><style>:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-black:#000;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-gray-100:#f8f9fa;--bs-gray-200:#e9ecef;--bs-gray-300:#dee2e6;--bs-gray-400:#ced4da;--bs-gray-500:#adb5bd;--bs-gray-600:#6c757d;--bs-gray-700:#495057;--bs-gray-800:#343a40;--bs-gray-900:#212529;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark:#212529;--bs-primary-rgb:13,110,253;--bs-secondary-rgb:108,117,125;--bs-success-rgb:25,135,84;--bs-info-rgb:13,202,240;--bs-warning-rgb:255,193,7;--bs-danger-rgb:220,53,69;--bs-light-rgb:248,249,250;--bs-dark-rgb:33,37,41;--bs-white-rgb:255,255,255;--bs-black-rgb:0,0,0;--bs-body-color-rgb:33,37,41;--bs-body-bg-rgb:255,255,255;--bs-font-sans-serif:system-ui,-apple-system,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue","Noto Sans","Liberation Sans",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";--bs-font-monospace:SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;--bs-gradient:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));--bs-body-font-family:var(--bs-font-sans-serif);--bs-body-font-size:1rem;--bs-body-font-weight:400;--bs-body-line-height:1.5;--bs-body-color:#212529;--bs-body-bg:#fff;--bs-border-width:1px;--bs-border-style:solid;--bs-border-color:#dee2e6;--bs-border-color-translucent:rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);--bs-border-radius:.375rem;--bs-border-radius-sm:.25rem;--bs-border-radius-lg:.5rem;--bs-border-radius-xl:1rem;--bs-border-radius-2xl:2rem;--bs-border-radius-pill:50rem;--bs-link-color:#0d6efd;--bs-link-hover-color:#0a58ca;--bs-code-color:#d63384;--bs-highlight-bg:#fff3cd}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:no-preference){:root{scroll-behavior:smooth}}body{margin:0;font-family:var(--bs-body-font-family);font-size:var(--bs-body-font-size);font-weight:var(--bs-body-font-weight);line-height:var(--bs-body-line-height);color:var(--bs-body-color);text-align:var(--bs-body-text-align);background-color:var(--bs-body-bg);-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}@charset "UTF-8";:root{--animate-duration:1s;--animate-delay:1s;--animate-repeat:1}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.95687808cf5f755e.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.95687808cf5f755e.css"></noscript></head>
        
        <body ng-version="14.2.2" ng-server-context="other">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet><!---->
        </body>
    </html>
```

It seems that the page is loading but the routing is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of trying to solve this problem I came across 1 post on stack overflow that did not have a lot of upvotes and was not the accepted answer. However, it was one of the few posts that had a lot of research behind. I followed @Sparker73 answer and finally my problem was solved.

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024686/deploy-angular-universal-to-iis/66505630#answer-62054963)

Answer (score 0):

All the steps are correct. And I have one suggestion for you.

1. Please check how to [set NODE_ENV=production on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9250168/7687666).

**Troubleshooting steps:**

If the suggestion above not useful to you.

1. Don't put the publish files under C drive.
2. Check the IIS Logs

Comment: It's driving me crazy, it's working perfectly fine locally but when publishing it on iis I get the above error. The website is published on the E drive and I checked the iis logs and everything seems fine.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Masri Do you mind create a sample project for us without any sensitive info. We can't reproduce the issue in our side.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Masri I mean the publish file, not your project.

Comment: I will copy the project and remove any sensitive information and share a link.

Comment: I uploaded both the source code and published file to git:
Published File: https://github.com/osamaelmasri/AngularSSR-Test

Source Code: https://github.com/osamaelmasri/AngularSSR-Test/tree/source_code

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Masri I am testing, pls wait...

Comment: @OsamaEl-Masri Try to navigate to ssr_demo folder and  use `node --trace-deprecation main.js` cmd to debug the application. Make sure close the port you used in IIS by killing the process.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it but I finally found the answer online. I'll post it here