# How to deploy angular universal on IIS

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, iis-10, iisnode

Can someone help me to deploy angular universal build on IIS server?
I have integrated angular universal in existing angular 13 project and its working fine. but my problem with deployment on IIS when deploying build as website it's working for example on root (https:[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) but I want this to deploy as application not website (https:[www.domain.com/myapp](http://www.domain.com/myapp)).
Where myapp is application which is under sites.
Facing issues like MIME type or unexpected syntax error for CSS/JS files.

Can someone please help me on this

Tried with [Deploy Angular Universal to IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024686/deploy-angular-universal-to-iis)

But this is for website, want to deploy as application on iis

Comment: `Facing issues like MIME type or unexpected syntax error for CSS/JS files`. It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, please post more details information about your error.