# install ghost CMS on windows

Tags: windows, iis, ghost-blog

I am trying to install ghost on a windows server and serve it with IIS but I couldn't find an official document for it and every unofficial document way gets an error at last and don't work properly I try one of them [here](https://darwich.mx/installing-ghost-on-iis-10/)
but at last I get the following error:
[image]
any solution or complete tutorial about it?

Comment: check that you give iis_iusrs and iusr access to use node js app folder. and check the log file for more detail.

Comment: i give all permission but problem still remain

Comment: which identity is used by your application pool? [image](https://i.imgur.com/4FoJhYB.jpg), could you share your site security settings?

Comment: i can share but i dont know how?

Comment: use this site https://imgur.com/upload and upload an image and share image link.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Vq2gAPK

Comment: try to permission to the folder "IIS AppPool\<apppoolname>".also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028537/iisnode-encountered-an-error-when-processing-the-request).